# PyWinRM Plugib - Executing inline powershell scripts returns unwanted #< CLIXML outputs streams

Tags: winrm, rundeck

**Link To PyWinRM issue below**:

[PyWinRM GIT Issue 39](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin/issues/39)

Been rebuilding and re-installing Rundeck over and over, im sure that +- a year ago & 6 months ago this did not happen.

Anyone else face this issue and have a known fix / workaround?

**Rundeck Job:**

```
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  group: Test/Example
  id: 0ff8c815-9a9f-4e1d-a277-1b50b8f9064c
  loglevel: INFO
  name: ls c:\
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: true
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: 'name: OVH.JUMP01.WinRMPython'
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - args: -windowstyle hidden
      fileExtension: ps1
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; ls c:\
      scriptInterpreter: powershell.exe
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 0ff8c815-9a9f-4e1d-a277-1b50b8f9064c
```

**Output:**

```
    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
d-----        9/28/2019   5:22 PM                inetpub                                                               
d-----        9/15/2018   9:19 AM                PerfLogs                                                              
d-r---       11/21/2019   3:54 PM                Program Files                                                         
d-----       11/19/2019   7:52 PM                Program Files (x86)                                                   
d-----        12/2/2019   3:26 PM                temp                                                                  
d-r---        10/7/2019   4:06 PM                Users                                                                 
d-----       10/12/2019   5:12 PM                Windows                                                               


[ERROR  ]  Execution finished with the following error (winrm-exec.py:267)[root]
[ERROR  ]  #< CLIXML
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><Obj S="progress" RefId="0"><TN RefId="0"><T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T><T>System.Object</T></TN><MS><I64 N="SourceId">1</I64><PR N="Record"><AV>Preparing modules for first use.</AV><AI>0</AI><Nil /><PI>-1</PI><PC>-1</PC><T>Completed</T><SR>-1</SR><SD> </SD></PR></MS></Obj></Objs> (winrm-exec.py:268)[root]
Failed to remove remote file: c:\temp\7-73-OVH.JUMP01.WinRMPython-dispatch-script.tmp.ps1
```

Comment: Hi, can you share your job exit in debug mode to take a look? Thanks!

Comment: Other questions: Which Windows, Python and Powershell versions are you using?

Comment: @MegaDrive Found [the issue:](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rundeck-discuss/8aM3AAugMuc) Python3x.... Use Python 2.7x 

The Rundeck plugin Git repo details python 2 or 3 required, appears 3x have this symptom present everywhere I tested.

Answer (score 1):

Found [the issue:](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rundeck-discuss/8aM3AAugMuc) Python3x.... Use Python 2.7x

The Rundeck plugin Git repo details python 2 or 3 required, appears 3x have this symptom present everywhere tested, regardless of windows node or powershell versions.

```
update-alternatives --config python
There are 3 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3     10        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3     10        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         manual mode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [latest](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin/releases/tag/2.0.5) plugin version, that issue seems [fixed](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin/issues/39#issuecomment-562302673).

Comment: awesome, I saw the release notes :-) will test over the weekend.